# Loadrunner C Code String Manipulation

Tags: c, loadrunner

I came across the below code while googling which works great. (Credit to Chaitanya Bhatt @ Performancecompetence.com)

The below function searches for the last occurrence of the passed delimiter and saves the remaining part of the input string to the returned output string.

```
void strLastOccr(char inputStr[100], char* outputStr, char *delim)
    {
        char *temp, *temp2;
        int i = 0;
        temp = "";
        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {   
                temp2 = temp;
                temp = (char *)strtok(inputStr,delim);
                i++;
            }
            if(i>0)
            {
                temp2 = temp;
                temp = (char *)strtok(NULL,delim);
            }
            lr_save_string(temp2,outputStr);
        }
    }
```

Basically trying to add two new options to pass in.

1. **Occurrence No:** Instead of defaulting to the last occurrence, allowing to specific which occurrence to stop at and save the remaining of the string.
2. **Part of the string to save: (Left, Right)** At the moment the string is saving the right side  once the delimiter is found. Additional option is intended to allow the user to specify for the left or right side of the delimiter is found.

   void strOccr(char inputStr[100], char* outputStr, char *delim, int *occrNo, char *stringSide)

So the question is what are the modifications I need to the above function?
Also is it actually possible to do?

**UPDATE**

After I kept at it I was able to workout a solution.

As I can't answer my own question for another 6 hours, points will be awarded to who can provide an improved function.  Specifically I don't like the code under the comment "// Removes the delim at the end of the string."

```
void lr_custom_string_delim_save (char inputStr[500], char* outputStr, char *delim, int occrNo, int stringSide)
{
    char *temp, *temp2;
    char temp3[500] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int i2;
    int iOccrNo = 1;
    temp = "";

    while (temp!=NULL) {
        if(i==0) {
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = (char *)strtok(inputStr,delim);
            i++;
        }

        if(i>0) {
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = (char *)strtok(NULL,delim);

            if (stringSide==0) {
                if (iOccrNo > occrNo) {
                    strcat(temp3, temp2);
                        // Ensure an extra delim is not added at the end of the string.
                        if (temp!=NULL) {
                            // Adds the delim back into the string that is removed by strtok.
                            strcat(temp3, delim);
                        }
                }
            }

            if (stringSide==1) {
                if (iOccrNo <= occrNo) {
                    strcat(temp3, temp2);
                    strcat(temp3, delim);
                }
            }
            // Increase the occurrence counter.
            iOccrNo++;
        }
    }

    // Removes the delim at the end of the string.
    if (stringSide==1) {
        for( i2 = strlen (temp3) - 1; i2 >= 0 
        && strchr ( delim, temp3[i2] ) != NULL; i2-- )
        // replace the string terminator:
        temp3[i2] = '\0';
        }

    // Saves the new string to new param.
    lr_save_string(temp3,outputStr);
}
```

Comment: What did you try that failed?

Comment: I got excited thinking Loadrunner was in reference to the video game I played on the Apple IIe decades ago! Time to fire up the emulator...

Comment: Have you tried to understand the code? What parts don't you understand? You can't change it very well if you don't understand it...

Comment: So I was able to understand that the following part of the code is were it is searching for the delim.   "temp2 = temp; ,temp = (char *)strtok(NULL,delim);"  However I got stuck on how to select just one of the matched strings. I tired a few options which none really worked.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need to make a few modifications.    As you begin walking the string with strtok() you can store two variables, char *current, *previous.

As you hit each new token, move 'current' to 'previous' and store the new 'current.'   At the end of the string parse look at the value of 'previous' to get the second from last element.

Other options, keep a counter and build a pseudo array using the LoadRunner variable handling mechanism, lr_save_string(token_value,"LR_variable_name_").   You'll need to build your variable name string first of course.    When you fall out of the parse action your count variable will likely hold the total number of token elements parsed out of the string and then you can use the (counter-1) index value to build your string.

```
char foo[100]="";
...
sprint(foo, "{LR_variable_name_%d}",counter-1);
lr_message("My second to last element is %s",lr_eval_string(foo));
```

There are likely other options as well, but these are the two that jump to mind.   Also, I recommend a book to you that I recommend to all that want to brush up on their C (including my brother and my uncle), "C for Dummies."    There are lots of great options here on the string processing front that you can leverage in LoadRunner.